# Using flags attribute in data access layer to generate bitwise SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, enums, bit-manipulation

I have a function in my data access layer. This function takes an enum (which has `[Flags]` attribute on it) as its only parameter.

```
[Flags]
public enum ItemTags { Browsable = 2, InMenu = 4 }

public List<Item> GetAllItems(ItemTags flags)
{
    // Here I should create the SQL bitwise query.
}
```

In this function, I should create a bitwise SQL query, something like:

```
select * from tableName where columnName & 2 = 2 and columnName & 4 = 4
```

And in my business layer, I want to use that function. But there are many possible ways to use those tags and flags. Some of these functions could be:

```
public List<Item> GetItemsOfMenu()
{
   return repository.GetAllItems(ItemTags.InMenu);
}

public List<Item> GetBrowsableItems()
{
   return repository.GetAllItems(ItemTags.Browsable);
}

public List<Item> GetBrowsableMenuItems()
{
   return repository.GetAllItems(ItemTags.Browsable & ItemTags.InMenu);
}
```

How can I do that?